# Storing HTML website archive on Sharepoint?

Tags: office-365, html, onedrive-for-business

I have an old intranet site that I've made an archive of using [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) - with the folder on my computer (either Mac or Windows), I can browse the copy fine.

What I'd like to do is upload it (somehow) to our Office 365 tenant - either SharePoint or Onedrive seem to be the way to go - but I can't figure out how to get Sharepoint to act as a "dumb" host. Is it even possible?

I see that I can sync SharePoint "folders" or whatever they are to local machines - and browsing would work that way, but it's more cumbersome.

Basically, is there a way to make SharePoint act like [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)? I'd like the sharing/security/login features of SharePoint, but I don't want to translate my site archive more than I have to.

I have no need or desire to edit the pages once they're up - in fact, I'd use GitHub Pages if it wasn't for the fact that those are public and I don't want to introduce a new tool if I don't have to (and I want to use our Office 365 subscriptions as much as possible).

[This](http://docs.teamstudio.com/display/EXPORT021/Storing+HTML+Sites+in+Microsoft+SharePoint) might be related though it seems to apply to a particular product.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ContentEditor webpart? It allows you to point to your HTML files stored in SharePoint and displays them in an IFRAME.

More documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc).

Comment: This sounds useful but darned if I can't figure how you "add a web part" - I go to where it seems I should be able to insert web part, media and content, but there's no "ContentEditor" - and I can't tell if I'm looking at a Classic or Modern page, and/or how to enable it in the admin panel.

Comment: It only works on classic pages and if your "home page" is modern, you can still add a web part page to your pages library. The web part page will display in classic mode.

The web part should show up in the category "Media and content". If it doesn't you have to allow Scripts in your tenant. Instructions below:

Go to SharePoint admin center, and then click on Settings.
Then select:
Allow users to run custom script on personal sites
Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites

Allow up to 24h for the change to propagate.

Comment: I've done the above, and it's been 48h and no new things appear. I notice that I have "Prevent creation of old version site collections, but allow creation of new version site collections. Allow opt-in upgrade to the new version site collections." and can't change it - could that be related? Do I have to create a "personal" site? I was trying to do this in a site created by making a group in Teams (I think that's where it came from).